# How long were O'Neill and Teal'c stuck in the time loop in "Window of Opportunity"?

Tags: time-travel, stargate, stargate-sg1

In season 4 episode 6 of *Stargate SG-1*, "Window of Opportunity", Jack O'Neill and Teal'c get stuck in a time loop, repeatedly living the same ten or so hours after a mission to a planet where they had encountered an ancient device powered by geomagnetic disturbances with the intention of being a time machine.

I've often wondered, how long were Jack O'Neill and Teal'c stuck in the time loop caused by this device? I have counted the number of individual days shown in the episode but there is mention of events that aren't shown in the show so I am convinced that this doesn't account for all of the days.

How many times did time repeat?

Comment: Wiki says 6 to 10 hours. I wonder which one it is...

Comment: That would be the time per loop.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Quote from the episode's transcript ([Source](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/4.06_%22Window_Of_Opportunity%22_Transcript))

> CARTER : We got a message from the Tok’ra. Apparently they’ve been
>   trying to contact us for over three months.
>
> O’NEILL looks up not surprised.
>
> O’NEILL : Really?
>
> CARTER : Who knows when they first realized that we were cut off. I
>   mean there’s really no telling how much time passed.

It's thus at least 3 months, but probably not 6. My guess is 3-4 months.

Comment: 3months,... 90 times Teal'c getting smacked in the face

Answer (score 2):

> O'NEILL: Daniel, you know how to read this stuff. Get up here and shut
> it off.
>
> DANIEL: What?
>
> [He walks up to the pedestal and stares at it.]
>
> DANIEL: Are you kidding me? I wouldn't even know where to begin, I mean
> it would take years to translate. I don't even have enough…
>
> <sub>*Stargate SG-1* - S04E06 - "[Window of Opportunity](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/4.06_%22Window_Of_Opportunity%22_Transcript)"</sub>

Looks like maybe a couple of years on the high side. Keep in mind that Daniel had to teach both Teal'c and Jack enough Ancient/Lantean to help him with the translations, which admittedly may have sped up the process some, as well as the fact that Teal'c and Jack both took loops off to goof around/unwind.

Comment: Daniel may be referring to the amount of time it would take in the normal course of affairs (e.g taking into account travel time, birthdays, weekends, other tasks, etc). With sufficient motivation, it may have only taken a few months

Comment: As I said, this was more on the high side of the estimation, ergo as little as two months and as many as 2 years.

Comment: He could also be exaggerating as is common when put on the spot. But this is a direct quoted from the episode keyed to a timeframe so +1